# Axiomatic descrption of Poincaré polynomial

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

One can define the Euler characteristic of a finite CW complex axiomatically as follows

Let  $\Psi$ be a function, which associates to any finite CW complex $X$ an interger $\Psi(X)$ satisfying the following axioms:

(a) For any two homeomorphic complexes $X$ and $Y$ we have $\Psi(X) = \Psi(Y)$.

(b) For a pair $A \subset X$ we have $\Psi(A)+\Psi(X/A)=\Psi(X)+1$

(c) $\Psi(point)=1$, $\Psi(\mathbb{S}^0)=2$.

Then it is not very hard to show (I think) that this agrees with the usual definition $\chi$. My question is if there is a similar set of axioms to define the Poincaré Polynomial.

Comment: It seems unlikely. The problem is what to do about Mayer-Vietoris / relative homology sequences where the connecting maps are nonzero.